# NodeMCU v0.9 - ESP8266-12 MicroPython Unable to access REPL (Python prompt)

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, micropython

I have a NodeMCU v0.9 which I have successfully flashed MicroPython on. I can't access the REPL using any of the methods listed on micropython docs - (picocom, thonny...)..

[image: board]

I'm able to access the REPL when using Arduino IDE, but every other software fails...
I would like to program the board with Thonny, but I can't get it to work. I'm always getting the error: Device is busy or does not respond....

[image: Arduino IDE]